# Name of the lion vahana of Maa Kamakhya or Maa Durga

Tags: puranas, durga, vahana, shakta, kamarupa

What is the name of the lion vahana of Maa Kamakhya or Maa Durga? I have heard the name of the vahana is Mahasingha or Dawon, but is there any scriptural reference that gives the accurate name of the vahana. I know that Somanandin is the name of the tiger as per Puranas which is a Devi gana or Shiva gana but not vahana of Maa Durga.

Comment: Not an answer, but supporting research. Searched the complete Devi Mahatmyam and the words used are Kesari, Simha, Mahasimha. Devi herself manifests as Narsinghi.

Answer (score 0):

**Sri Kālika Upa-Purana Chapter 58.:**

> विष्णुब्रह्माशिवैरदेवै ध्रियते सा जगन्मयी।
>
> **सितप्रेतो महादेवो ब्रह्मा लोहित पङ्कजं।।** 65
>
> This Jaganmayi Devi Shivā is always borne by Vishnu, Brahma and Shiva; **for Mahadeva is the preta and Brahma is pink lotus.**
>
> **हरिर्हरिस्तु विज्ञेयो वाहनानि मनोजसः।**
>
> स्वमूर्त्या वाहनत्वन्तु तेषषा यस्मान्न युज्यते ।। 66
>
> **Hari is lion, and these Tridevas serve as Vahanas of the illustrious Devi.** However, the three of them cannot attain Devi's Vahanatva in their individual forms.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

The name of Maa Durga's lion is Simhamukha. The **[5th chapter](https://archive.org/details/SriSkandaPuranam-SankaraSamhitaPart1/page/n202/mode/1up?view=theater)** of Upadesha Khanda of Sankara Samhita from Skanda Purana mentioned Simhamukha's story :-

---

```
Note: The source has long story and also it's not available in english, but i self-translated and shortened the story.
```

Once, there was a king named Prabhakara and he has four sons, whose names are Sura, Padma, Simhamukha, Taraka (not Tarakasura). Later, Sura-Padma devoted to Kartikeya and Simhamukha-Taraka devoted with  Durga and Dharmasastha.

As soon, Sura & Padma become Kartikeya's vehicles, Taraka become Dharmasastha's elephant vehicle and Simhamukha become lion vehicle of Durga.